# Generic class that accepts C++ string & C style string

Tags: c++, c, string

So as you know:
C style string is a character array that end with "null"

C++ style string is:

```
string s = "Some text";
```

So to accept both C++ string and C style string, I'm pretty sure I have to use C++ template.

**I'm trying to write a class and a method that returns the second character of the string for C++ or C style string. Am I on the right track?**

```
template <class T>
  class mystring {
    T pointer;

  public:
    mystring(T input) { pointer = input }
    char getSecondLetter() {
      T temp = pointer;
      temp++;
      return temp;
    }
};

int main () {
  mystring<I dont know what to put> myobject("HELLO");
  cout << myobject.getSecondLetter();
  return 0;
}
```

p.s. Do programmers always use 'T' for template class datatype?

Comment: Define "accept". Is there something a `std::string` does *not* do for you that you need (and in answering that, consider the `c_str()` member that allows it to present externally as a null-terminated string). ? Apart from that, must it be a class/method? Why not just a pair of overloaded functions?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your comment =( I'm trying to implement my own function/class without using given library functions that will accept either c or cpp string and do some operations on the string

Comment: @JL No, programmers don't always use `T`, but it's the standard.

Comment: @timss it is not the "standard". I think you meant the `convention` :)

Comment: @user2280716 Ah yes, that's the word I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 4):

there is no need, C string implicit convert to std::string

```
char getSecondLetter( const std::string & s ) {
  return s[1];
}

const char *c_str = "hello";
std::string str = "world";

getSecondLetter( c_str );   // e
getSecondLetter( str );     // o
```

Comment: Thank you. But I already knew c_str() method, and did not want to use it. I'm trying to practice "generic class" and trying to learn how to use generic class to accept c style string or cpp string and do operations such as return char at index X or capitalize a character etc.

Comment: better to use `const char* c_str = "hello"` since `char*` is deprecated for string literal.

Comment: The volatile pointer `c_str` will be flagged by an self-respecting modern C++ compiler as a deprecated feature. It should be declared as an initialized array or a `const char*` to be compliant.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a template:

```
template<typename Str_T>
char getSecondLetter(Str_T const & str) { return str[1]; }
```

That will allow both `std::string` and `char const*`.  But it will also allow anything else that happens to have an `operator[]` that returns a char, or something convertible to a char(e.g. `std::vector<char>`, or `std::deque<char>`).  If you want to limit it to just `std::string` and `char const*`, then you can just write two overloads:

```
char getSecondLetter(std::string const & str) { return str[1]; }
char getSecondLetter(char const * str) { return str[1]; }
```

Of course, you can also do as others have shown, and just make one version that takes a `std::string`.  But be aware that if you pass a c-string to it, the conversion to `std::string` will likely result in a memory allocation, only to be deallocated when the function ends.

Comment: +1 The multi-use upshot is a bonus and will at least make the OP think about how templates expand to encompass more than he may have first considered. Nice answer.

Comment: Hmm.. Well yes, theoretically I would only want std::string & char const*, but if the two overload methods mentioned are used, I dont think the class is considered as a generic class anymore. The parameter for the functions are already defined datatype, not generic. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need templates for this - you can actually just use this:

```
class mystring {
    std::string str;
public:
    mystring(std::string input) : str(input) {}
    char getSecondLetter() {
        return str[1];
    }
};
```

Since std::string has a constructor that takes a `const char*`, when you write `mystring("hello")`, your const char* will be implicitly converted to an std::string using the string constructor before being passed to your class constructor.

Comment: avoiding the double construct, `const std::string& input` would be a better match, but even then, it makes a copy of the input, which I'm not convinced the OP is looking for (not surprisingly).

Answer (score 0):

boost::string_ref may be what you're looking for: [http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html]

It's a lightweight class that can be constructed from a string or c-array, and it supports the immutable portion of the std::string interface.