# Can you have methods with specific datatypes for generic class?

Tags: c++, templates

This was my previous question:
[Generic class that accepts C++ string & C style string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116641/generic-class-that-accepts-c-string-c-style-string)

Benjamin Lindley answer seemed to be what I was looking for.
He said that since I only want to limit it to just std::string and char const*, then I should just use two overloads:

```
char getSecondLetter(std::string const & str) { return str[1]; }
char getSecondLetter(char const * str) { return str[1]; }
```

But if I use two overloads, the parameters for these overload methods are datatypes are not generic.

```
char getSecondLetter(T const & str) { return str[1]; }
```

So the datatype is not T or Str_T but it is std::string or char const*. If I use these overloaded methods for a generic class, I believe the class is not really generic anymore. Am I correct or am I wrong?...

Comment: You are probably wrong, but your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Are you asking whether template specialization decreases genericism?

Comment: It looks like he said "***if*** you want to limit it..."  Is that what you want?

Comment: Well basically can a generic class have methods with parameters for specific datatypes instead of being general datatype T? If I have overloaded method, my class will invoke the overloaded methods for specific datatypes. I dont know if this is still considered as generic class anymore.

Schnommus// Oh ok... maybe I think I am asking that question. I dont fully understand the term template specialization, but I think that is the question.

Comment: It is "generic" if you decide to call it "generic". The term "generic" has no specific meaning in relation to C++ classes. Why does it matter if the resulting class is "generic" or not, as long as it does what you need?

Comment: Oh my assignment said to create 'generic class'. So I thought generic class means that I have to use template <class T> and have my methods to accepts parameters only with datatype T

Comment: Of course you can. Look at `std::vector::reserve` or `std::vector::resize`.

Comment: I think you may be confusing C++ template metaprogramming with generics from other languages like Java. They are not the same.